# Laravel API JSON Request change property names

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there any solutions on how to change property names or attributes of JSON Request in Laravel?

Something like Eloquent API Resources but instead in responses, it will be done in requests before directing to the request validation?

From this,

```
{
    "agent_reference": "ABC-12345",
    "product_instance_id": "aca68c65-44c3-4ea1-a726-ca183de09a31",
    "add_ons": [
        "string"
    ],
    "transportation": "string",
    "guests": [
        {
        "guest_type_key": "string",
        "add_ons": [
            "string"
        ],
        "field_responses": [
            {
            "key": "string",
            "response": "string"
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To this,

```
{
    "agent_id": "ABC-12345",
    "plan_id": "aca68c65-44c3-4ea1-a726-ca183de09a31",
    "additional_params": [
        "string"
    ],
    "pickup_place": "string",
    "visitors": [
        {
        "visitor_kty": "string",
        "additional_params": [
            "string"
        ],
        "responses": [
            {
            "id": "string",
            "result": "string"
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 4 had support for such a thing, however, sadly, it got removed with the release of Laravel 5.

**For Laravel 5.2+**, the "neat" way of achieving this is is by overriding the `validationData()` method in your `App\Http\Requests\FormRequest` class.

Take a look at:

### Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest

```php
protected function validationData()
{
    return $this->all();
}
```

The function above is meant to return all inputs that will be sent to the validation, `$this` is the Request itself.

So, in your `App\Http\Requests\FormRequest` class, you define the very same method, get the inputs, sanitize as you want (even creating a whole new structure with different key names, as requested in your question), replace it in the request to persist and return, like so:

```php
/**
 * Get data to be validated from the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function validationData()
{
    $inputs = $this->all();

    // Sanitize $inputs as your likes.

    $this->replace($inputs); // To persist.

    return $this->all();
}
```

This is how you get it done in **Laravel 5.2+**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this sir but the thing is how can i change those property names especially nested arrays attributes in order to pass in this validationData function?

Comment: There's no out of the box way to achieve this with Laravel, you'll have to tackle it with pure php.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer sir. God bless.